# How to load pdf file and print using Neodynamic PrintUtils settings c#

Tags: c#, pdf, thermal-printer, neodynamic

How to load pdf file and print using this settings?

```
PrintUtils.PrinterSettings.Communication.CommunicationType = CommunicationType.USB;
PrintUtils.PrinterSettings.ProgrammingLanguage = ProgrammingLanguage.ZPL;
PrintUtils.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "PrinterName";
PrintUtils.AutoSetLabelLength();
PrintUtils.CutLabel();
```

example:

```
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
doc.LoadFromFile("FileName");
```

that "doc.LoadFromFile("FileName");" works with neodynamic printutils? If yes, how?